# Getting an error when opening a website in Visual Studio 2022

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to create a website using Visual Studio 2022 Community edition, and when I open a website (File/Open/Website) in local IIS that I created, there was a message saying that the "Target framework is not supported".

When I choose update the target to .NET Framework 4.8 and click continue, there is an error message saying

> Error parsing the web configuration file at line 1. A document must contain exactly one root element.

How can I fix this? Thanks.

This is the screen shot:

[image: Target framework not supported]

and the error I get:

[image: Error]

Comment: Well - you'll need to **at least** show us that web config file !! How can we tell you what's wrong if we don't see what you have?!?!?!

Comment: I don't know how to get to the web config. The website is unloaded, cant find it in the solution explorer.

Comment: Just got this and the web.config does not exist for a web site until you select 'Yes' to upgrade to 4.8. It then creates a completely empty web.config.

Comment: See my answer below - the web.config is created on the fly by VS and is in the root directory of your web site. Edit the web.config to fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else that gets this issue. What happens is that you have a web site that is not even a web project in the VS sense and you open it from VS 2022. VS creates an empty web.config file on the fly and because it is empty, you see the error above. To fix this you should open the web.config in a text editor and just add an empty configuration element:

```
<configuration></configuration>
```

Save the web.config, and in VS, right-click the web site root and do 'Reload project'. That fixed it for me.

Answer (score -2):

i got your question. here are the simple steps to rid of that issue.
[error parsing the cong file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kjdjn.png)

first of all get into the folder of VS-2022, in which your new website is saved.[folder of website](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRepo.png)
after heading into the folder you can find the cong file which is completely empty.

open the empty cong file and write
`<configuration></configuration>`
into the file and save it.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OYe4q.png)
now get back into the vs studio 2022, open your project and hit reload the new website boom your issue  got resolved.

Comment: There is already an answer with the exact same solution as yours, how is your answer any different?